# Dynamically created TextBoxes not saving values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating the dynamic text boxes and buttons but when I add values it does not save any thing with I enter into the  data base. Well it does not give any error when I enter the values. please tell me if I am doing any thing wrong.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["clicks"] = "";
}


protected void btnCU_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button Ad_AB = new Button();
    Ad_AB.ID = "btnAd_add";
    Ad_AB.Text = "Add";
    Ad_AB.Click += new EventHandler(Ad_AB_Click);

    TextBox txtAd_AUN = new TextBox();
    TextBox txtAd_AP = new TextBox();
    txtAd_AUN.ID = "txtAd_AUN".ToString() ;
    txtAd_AP.ID = "txtAd_AP".ToString() ;

    Label lblAd_AEUN = new Label();
    Label lblAd_AEP = new Label();
    lblAd_AEUN.Text = "Enter User Name :";
    lblAd_AEP.Text = "Enter Passowrd :";

    pnlCNU.Controls.Add(Ad_AB);
    pnlCNU.Controls.Add(lblAd_AEUN);
    pnlCNU.Controls.Add(txtAd_AUN);
    pnlCNU.Controls.Add(lblAd_AEP);
    pnlCNU.Controls.Add(txtAd_AP);

    if(Session["clicks"].ToString() == "G"){
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Omer\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WAPPassignment\\App_Data\\LoginStuff.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;

        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into WhatTypes(UserName, Password) Values ('" + txtAd_AUN.Text + "', '" + txtAd_AP.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

}

void Ad_AB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    Session["clicks"] = "G";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the dynamically added controls are added at the init or preinit stage, they will not persist beyond a postback. Controls added after this need to be recreated on each post back.

But in your case, I would suggest that you just create the controls at design time inside a div or panel with its Visible property set to false and then when the button is clicked, just change the Visible property to true. It looks like you just want to show some login boxes when the button is clicked.